# Pandas - Timestamp-Index handling and resampling of multiple timestamp indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a complex problem which I will try to explain:

I have the following DataFrame as Base:

```
                                            value
A   B                   C
111 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 00:00:00 1
111 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 01:00:00 2
111 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 02:00:00 3
222 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 03:00:00 4
222 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 04:00:00 5
222 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 05:00:00 6
```

As you can see there is one index `A` which shall be preservered.
Index `B` is grouped by Day. - Index `C` is grouped by Hour.

Besides this Base DataFrame I have some date_ranges:
a)

```
2024-02-05 00:00:00
2024-02-06 00:00:00
```

b)

```
2024-02-05 22:00:00
2024-02-05 23:00:00
2024-02-06 22:00:00
2024-02-06 23:00:00
```

The result I want to achieve is the following DataFrame:

```
                                            value
A   B                   C
111 2024-02-05 00:00:00 2024-02-05 22:00:00 0
222 2024-02-05 00:00:00 2024-02-05 22:00:00 0
111 2024-02-05 00:00:00 2024-02-05 23:00:00 0
222 2024-02-05 00:00:00 2024-02-05 23:00:00 0
111 2024-02-06 00:00:00 2024-02-06 22:00:00 0
222 2024-02-06 00:00:00 2024-02-06 22:00:00 0
111 2024-02-06 00:00:00 2024-02-06 23:00:00 0
222 2024-02-06 00:00:00 2024-02-06 23:00:00 0
111 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 00:00:00 1
222 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 00:00:00 0
111 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 01:00:00 2
222 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 01:00:00 0
111 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 02:00:00 3
222 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 02:00:00 0
111 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 03:00:00 0
222 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 03:00:00 4
111 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 04:00:00 0
222 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 04:00:00 5
111 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 05:00:00 0
222 2024-03-22 00:00:00 2024-03-22 05:00:00 6
```

Now my questions are:

- How can I achieve all of that?
- Is date_range even the correct way to provide such information? -> The only input I have is start and end-date with time for a day.

It could also happen that there will be a Index D which is grouped by minute.

If you need any more information please let me know.

> Pandas Version: 2.0.1

Thanks in advance.

Regards Oliver

Answer (score 0):

You can simply generate all the combinations of unique values in `A`, `B` and `C` this way

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': [111, 111, 111, 222, 222, 222],
    'B': ['2024-03-22 00:00:00', '2024-03-22 00:00:00', '2024-03-22 00:00:00',
          '2024-03-22 00:00:00', '2024-03-22 00:00:00', '2024-03-22 00:00:00'],
    'C': ['2024-03-22 00:00:00', '2024-03-22 01:00:00', '2024-03-22 02:00:00',
          '2024-03-22 03:00:00', '2024-03-22 04:00:00', '2024-03-22 05:00:00'],
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'])
df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C'])

date_ranges = {
    'a': pd.date_range(start='2024-02-05', end='2024-02-06', freq='D'),
    'b': pd.date_range(start='2024-02-05 22:00:00', end='2024-02-06 23:00:00', freq='H')
}

unique_combinations = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['A'].unique(), date_ranges['a'], date_ranges['b']], names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
all_combinations_df = pd.DataFrame(index=unique_combinations).reset_index()
all_combinations_df['value'] = 0

result_df = pd.concat([df, all_combinations_df]).fillna(0).astype({'value': int})

print(result_df)
```

which gives you

```
       A          B                   C  value
0    111 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 00:00:00      1
1    111 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 01:00:00      2
2    111 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 02:00:00      3
3    222 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 03:00:00      4
4    222 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 04:00:00      5
..   ...        ...                 ...    ...
99   222 2024-02-06 2024-02-06 19:00:00      0
100  222 2024-02-06 2024-02-06 20:00:00      0
101  222 2024-02-06 2024-02-06 21:00:00      0
102  222 2024-02-06 2024-02-06 22:00:00      0
103  222 2024-02-06 2024-02-06 23:00:00      0

[110 rows x 4 columns]
```

It is not arranged in the same way as your expected output, but you can do this the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you’ll need to take a couple of steps to massage the data in their current
form. From a data perspective, it is important that index level
'B' is derived from 'C' so for this solution I focus on working with
columns 'A' and 'C' and then re-derive 'B' as a final step at the end.

### Data

```py
from io import StringIO

raw = StringIO('''
A    B                    C                    value
111  2024-03-22 00:00:00  2024-03-22 00:00:00  1
111  2024-03-22 00:00:00  2024-03-22 01:00:00  2
111  2024-03-22 00:00:00  2024-03-22 02:00:00  3
222  2024-03-22 00:00:00  2024-03-22 03:00:00  4
222  2024-03-22 00:00:00  2024-03-22 04:00:00  5
222  2024-03-22 00:00:00  2024-03-22 05:00:00  6
''')


import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(raw, sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', parse_dates=['B', 'C'])

print(df)
#      A          B                   C  value
# 0  111 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 00:00:00      1
# 1  111 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 01:00:00      2
# 2  111 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 02:00:00      3
# 3  222 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 03:00:00      4
# 4  222 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 04:00:00      5
# 5  222 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 05:00:00      6
```

### Solution

To solve this problem, we’ll need to take the following steps.

1. create the additional ranges we want to include.
2. create the cartesian product of the current columns 'A' & 'C'.
3. combine the indexes generated from steps 1 & 2.
4. reindex the DataFrame using the new index.
5. derive column 'B'
6. massage to reflect OP’s specific ordering of output

```py
additional_ranges = [                                              # ①
    date + pd.Timedelta(hours=hours)
    for date in pd.date_range('2024-02-05', '2024-02-06', freq='D')
    for hours in [22, 23]
]

new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(                           # ② & ③
    [df['A'].unique(), [*df['C'].unique(), *additional_ranges]], 
    names=['A', 'C']
)

out = (
    df.set_index(['A', 'C']).reindex(new_index, fill_value=0)
    .sort_index(level=['C', 'A'])                                 # ④
    .assign(B=lambda d: d.index.get_level_values('C').floor('D')) # ⑤
    .set_index('B', append=True)                                  # ⑥
    .reorder_levels(['A', 'B', 'C'])
)

print(out)
#                                     value
# A   B          C
# 111 2024-02-05 2024-02-05 22:00:00      0
# 222 2024-02-05 2024-02-05 22:00:00      0
# 111 2024-02-05 2024-02-05 23:00:00      0
# 222 2024-02-05 2024-02-05 23:00:00      0
# 111 2024-02-06 2024-02-06 22:00:00      0
# 222 2024-02-06 2024-02-06 22:00:00      0
# 111 2024-02-06 2024-02-06 23:00:00      0
# 222 2024-02-06 2024-02-06 23:00:00      0
# 111 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 00:00:00      1
# 222 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 00:00:00      0
# 111 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 01:00:00      2
# 222 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 01:00:00      0
# 111 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 02:00:00      3
# 222 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 02:00:00      0
# 111 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 03:00:00      0
# 222 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 03:00:00      4
# 111 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 04:00:00      0
# 222 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 04:00:00      5
# 111 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 05:00:00      0
# 222 2024-03-22 2024-03-22 05:00:00      6
```